# How to set up an intercept-only mixed logistic regression in order to test for difference from 50% chance level?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

In my experiment, subjects repeatedly had to make a binary choice between A and B, and I want to test if subjects (as a group) differed from 50% chance in preferring A over B. Is there a way to test this using a mixed logistic regression, e.g. with `glmer()` in R?

The intercept only model, if I recall correctly, tests whether subjects as a whole differed from zero. But if I try to recode the dependent measure so that each score is a difference from chance (.5), and then test if that difference from chance differs from zero, then the model won't run because the value of the dependent measure has to be 0 or 1.

Is there some other way to do this using `glmer()` or is there a more straightforward way that I'm overlooking? Does it depend on how many trials are making up the dependent measure?

Comment: (+1) Interesting question. Multiple possible answers, and that is in and of itself, interesting.

Comment: Isn't it simply `glmer(choice ~ 1 + (1|subject), family=binomial)` ? P-value for the intercept is what you are looking for. Zero intercept in logistic regression corresponds to 50% chance of choosing A or B.

Comment: @amoeba, really? Is this easy to demonstrate, explain, or find sources for? If you do something like this in an answer then the bounty is yours (if you want it). I originally did it the way you suggest but I thought it was wrong, since this would be wrong in OLS regression. In OLS, you would subtract 'chance' (in this case .5) from each score and then run lm(choice ~ 1, data). But obviously I can't do the same here. Maybe I've been overthinking it and am failing to see the obvious? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confused about the role of intercept in logistic regression.

Logistic regression predicts the probability of some outcome, in your case e.g. the probability of the A choice. To do that, it forms a linear combination of predictors and passes it through a logistic function that "squeezes" real numbers from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ into a $[0,1]$ interval. It looks like that (image [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_function,_odds,_odds_ratio,_and_logit)):

$\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

So if the linear combination has value 0 then the output of logistic function is $p=0.5$. This means that a logistic regression without any predictors whatsoever and with zero intercept predicts 50% chance.

If you had 1 data point per subject, you could have used

```
glm(choice ~ 1, family='binomial')
```

and looked at the value and p-value for the intercept. In your case you have more than 1 data point per subject, so you can use

```
glmer(choice ~ 1 + (1|subject), family='binomial')
```

Comment: So just to be super clear, really one is comparing these two nested models (using the glm case for simplicity, which extends to glmer): glm(choice ~ 0, family ='binomial) and glm(choice ~ 1, family ='binomial). If the latter model is a better fit, then the probability of A in the data set (which is what the intercept of 1 tests) is more informative than 0, which is actually chance, as you've described. You don't have to modify your answer to include this but it's helpful for me to think through why using an intercept of 1 is what you need. Thanks!

Comment: @PanPsych Wait, but you do understand that `choice ~ 1` does *not* mean that the intercept is set to 1, right? This just means that `glm` should estimate the intercept, and it can come out as any value, e.g. 0.42. I guess you know that, but you wrote "which is what the intercept of 1 tests" so I wanted to double-check that you understand that it's not the intercept equal to 1.

Comment: I don't think PanPsych's comment suggests the intercept itself is 1, but rather that the intercept is used. All of the rest of the comment makes that clear: the question is whether choice ~ 0 (that is, no intercept, or intercept===0) is any worse a fit than choice ~ 1 (i.e., 1*B0)

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, that is probably what PanPsych meant (and it is correct then). I just wanted to be sure (also for future readers).

Comment: @amoeba, yes, I understand that, but thanks for asking for that clarification. I should have used my language more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest use of a [Binomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test), with $p=0.5$.

One common use of the binomial test is in the case where the null hypothesis is that two categories are equally likely to occur (such as a coin toss). Tables are widely available to give the significance observed numbers of observations in the categories for this case. However, the binomial test is not restricted to this case, and can be used for any probability.

Edit: The above assumes that each subject is "cut from the same cloth." That is, that the probability, whatever that is, of choosing A or B is the same for each participant, and that each choice of A or B is performed only once. As a counterexample, suppose that subjects 1 and 2 would have perfect discordance in choices between the A and B objects. In that latter hypothetical case, our ability to detect even a perfect bias for each subject would be diminished, e.g., Subject 1 chooses only B 100 times while subject 2 chooses only A 100 times for a $P=0.5$. Clearly, from that hypothetical example, a lack of bias for overall choices is not equivalent to a lack of subject preference.

There is not enough information provided about the experiment in the question above nor its participants to model this further. For example, the ability or inability to measure concordance is not presented and we have a perfect absence of context as to what is being adjudicated as A or B and how that occurs. For example, two judges pairwise adjudicating whether the A or B face of a dirty coin is showing is different than two judges adjudicating two separate piles of dirty coins with no overlapping opinions. We do not know if we are asking whether the judges are biased, if the "A vs B" coins are biased, and that neither collectively or separately. This problem is complicated enough, by itself, that it deserves separate treatment, so, I made it into a question of its own [elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/332695/99274).

Comment: Does a binomial test account for the linked observations (same subject giving more than one data point)?

Comment: @PanPsych See Edit above.

Comment: @amoeba This is a very R question. I provided a method of answering what I understood of the data. A bit more about what the variables are and what is in the data would help. In particular, I do not know if glmer applies to the data.

Comment: it would help me if you could be specific about what you don't understand about the data that would help you answer the question. I tried to provide the essential details and yes, glmer() applies. I need to run logistic regression (responses were categorical/dichotomous) and I have multiple observations per participant.

Comment: Carl, apologies, I have deleted my comment above (before you answered).

Comment: @PanPsych Are subjects' responses highly correlated or not?

Comment: @Carl, they are likely correlated. This is something that is assumed and therefore must be accounted for in the model.  Not accounting for it is not good practice and inflates the type I error rate.

Comment: Yes, but how does one account for it? Take a look at the [linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/332695/99274) that this train of thought led me too. It does not seem simple. That is why I wanted more information from you about the problem. Without that, it is hard to know.